# Couldn't load assembly because of mismatching build number

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, .net-standard

Right now im restructuring my projects so I'll be able to target multiple frameworks.
Currently my solution is structured like this

```
MyProject (Solution)
    MyProject.Server (Project targeting net462)
    MyProject.Models (Project targeting netstandard2.0)
    MyProject.DataAccess (Project targeting netstandard2.0)
```

Models and DataAcces both reference `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql, Version=2.1.1.0` via NuGet.
Models holds my database models and the database context while DataAccess contains a UnitOfWork pattern.
This worked fine when all projects targeted netfx and used EntityFramework 6 for database connections.
The projects just build fine and I dont have any problems to start them (I should probably mention here, that my project is a type of resource for a multiplayer modification. The resource files get loaded like this https://github.com/GTANetworkDev/platform/blob/master/Server/Resources.cs#L198 `ourResource.Info.Info.Shadowcopy` is in this case false).
But once my resource wants to open a connection to the database I get a kinda huge exception telling me that `System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.0.0` is unable to load because of a version mismatch (https://hastebin.com/wodojakure.log).
The file `System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll` exists but with following attributes

```
AssemblyVersion=4.2.1.0
AssemblyFileVersion=4.6.26515.06
```

I've already tried using a `app.config` to rebind the assembly which failed, for a reason that I don't really know.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" /> 
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.1.0" newVersion="4.2.1.0" /> 
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

The app.config existed in the same folder where the other resource dlls are placed in and in the same folder where the server executable lays in.

Comment: Can you please add a question? Its not really clear what exactly you are asking

Comment: Right-click the solution in visual studio, then select Manage NuGet packages for the solution. then select Consolidate. then refer to the same version of the assembly and install/update.

Comment: The projects both reference the same version of `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` as you can see in the entry post. Nothing to consolidate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is, that the executable (which then invokes my dll) needs a config file where you specify the binding redirects and not the invoked dll itself.

Now it works like a charm. Thanks for the people trying to solve the problem.